Neovim (Windows) with LazyVim Only Loading 4/42 Plugins
enter image description here
I'm using Neovim on Windows 11 with LazyVim, but only 4 out of 42 plugins are loading. I've done a clean install of both Neovim and LazyVim, but many plugins remain unloaded, and I can't figure out why.
I already
Ran :Lazy sync to ensure all plugins were installed and synchronized.
Ran :checkhealth and checked for any errors or missing dependencies.
Restarted Neovim multiple times.
Ensured that no plugins are intentionally lazy-loaded unless specified.

In lazy.nvim, all plugins are lazy loaded by default. if you want to override that behaviour, you can set:
require("lazy").setup({
  defaults = { lazy = false },
}

If you want to make a specific plugin not lazy, you can do this:
require("yourplugin").setup({
  lazy = false,
  ...
}

It’s better to keep it lazy however, to decrease startup times.
